# How to remove element from all sub arrays in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

How can I remove all "aFHJBrKu54y5mWjY3" in "newFor"?

Trying do this, but it does not work.

```
        Messages.update({
                users: { $all: ["CnugxoBWs4ox6vG2k", "aFHJBrKu54y5mWjY3"] }
            },
            {
                $pull: {
                    "messages.$.newFor": "aFHJBrKu54y5mWjY3"
                }
            },
            { multi: true }
        );
```

```
{
    "_id" : "gQnYi2e54zADwgipx",
    "users" : [ 
        "aFHJBrKu54y5mWjY3", 
        "CnugxoBWs4ox6vG2k"
    ],
    "lastMessageAt" : ISODate("2020-06-22T22:50:35.579Z"),
    "messages" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "4d2219d05645a3991d3aae89",
            "addedAt" : ISODate("2020-06-22T22:50:35.579Z"),
            "userId" : "CnugxoBWs4ox6vG2k",
            "newFor" : [ 
                "aFHJBrKu54y5mWjY3",
                "CnugxoBWs4ox6vG2k"
            ],
            "message" : "Test"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "b42641118bb080cb9122062f",
            "addedAt" : ISODate("2020-06-22T22:48:24.359Z"),
            "userId" : "aFHJBrKu54y5mWjY3",
            "newFor" : [
                "aFHJBrKu54y5mWjY3"
            ],
            "message" : "Test 2"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "244e77bb8324dc0b0f0e2def",
            "addedAt" : ISODate("2020-06-22T22:48:14.643Z"),
            "userId" : "CnugxoBWs4ox6vG2k",
            "newFor" : [ 
                "aFHJBrKu54y5mWjY3"
            ],
            "message" : "Test 3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test yourself my answer: https://mongoplayground.net/p/vHx3J4zQgWr

**Query:**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "messages": {
        // for every element of messages array
        "$map": {
          "input": "$messages",
          "as": "m",
          "in": {
            // keep id
            "id": "$$m.id",
            // keep addedAt
            "addedAt": "$$m.addedAt",
            // keep userId
            "userId": "$$m.userId",
            // keep message
            "message": "$$m.message",
            // for every element of newFor, remove based on filter
            // $ne means "not equal"
            "newFor": {
              "$filter": {
                "input": "$$m.newFor",
                "as": "n",
                "cond": {
                  "$ne": [
                    "$$n",
                    "aFHJBrKu54y5mWjY3"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Result:**

```
[
  {
    "_id": "gQnYi2e54zADwgipx",
    "messages": [
      {
        "addedAt": ISODate("2020-06-22T22:50:35.579Z"),
        "id": "4d2219d05645a3991d3aae89",
        "message": "Test",
        "newFor": [
          "CnugxoBWs4ox6vG2k"
        ],
        "userId": "CnugxoBWs4ox6vG2k"
      },
      {
        "addedAt": ISODate("2020-06-22T22:48:24.359Z"),
        "id": "b42641118bb080cb9122062f",
        "message": "Test 2",
        "newFor": [],
        "userId": "aFHJBrKu54y5mWjY3"
      },
      {
        "addedAt": ISODate("2020-06-22T22:48:14.643Z"),
        "id": "244e77bb8324dc0b0f0e2def",
        "message": "Test 3",
        "newFor": [],
        "userId": "CnugxoBWs4ox6vG2k"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The [positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/index.html) `$` only matches the first array element that satisfies the query.  Since you have not specified any criteria for `messages` in the query, it will not match anything.

In order to remove the elements from every `newFor` array nested within an anonymous object nested within the `messages` array, you will need to iterate the `messages` array, and filter each of the `newFor` arrays separately.

This is only possible in a single update command if you are using MongoDB 4.2+, using the pipeline form of the update database command.

```
db.messages.update({},[
    {$set:{
        messages:{
            $map:{
                input:"$messages",
                in:{
                    $mergeObjects:[
                        "$$this",
                        {newFor:{
                            $filter:{
                                input:"$$this.newFor",
                                as:"new",
                                cond:{$not:{$in:[
                                    "$$new",        
                                    ["aFHJBrKu54y5mWjY3","CnugxoBWs4ox6vG2k"]
                                ]}}
                            }
                         }}
                     ]
                }
             }
        }
    }}
])
```